# how can i include System.Identity Model 4.0 in ASP.NetCore 2.1 mvc application

Tags: saml-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, sustainsys-saml2, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

What is the best approach to achieve saml2.0 in ASP.NetCore2.1 MVC application?

i am using Sustainsys.AspNetCore2.1Saml2 nuget, below is code. but the EntityId in it requires System.IdentityModel.dll 4.0 sounds like i am not able to run the application it shows below error.

Code

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
           .AddSaml2(options =>
           {
               options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("https://localhost:44349/Saml2");
               options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                   new IdentityProvider(
                       new EntityId("http://localhost:59410//Metadata"), options.SPOptions)
                   {
                       LoadMetadata = true
                   });

               options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx"));
           });
```

i am getting below error

[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing. any answer to issue i am facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can support SAML 2.0 in ASP.NET Core 2.1 by using ITfoxtec Identity Saml2. NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore/

Project https://itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2 and code samples https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test